# The counter is a negative value in some cases. Why? And How to solve this?

Tags: java, concurrency

```
package threadapps;

public class Threads extends javax.realtime.RealtimeThread{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    static volatile  boolean stop = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // TODO code application logic here
        //
        Thread a = new Threads();
        Thread b = new Threads();
        //set priority for threads
        a.setPriority(4);
        b.setPriority(6);
        //run threads
        a.start();
        b.start();
        //Sleep Thread
        Threads.sleep(5000);
        stop = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        // for loop for counting to 10
        //for(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
        //    System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName()+" The Counter Is "+i);
        //}    
        int count = 0;
        for(;!stop;)
            count++;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" The Count is "+count);
    }
}
```

Run this code and see the results. Can it be negative in some cases?

Comment: Do you have any question?

Comment: The code won't even compile. But what is your question?

Comment: For God's sake, there is no Threads class in Java. Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: copy the code from above the code written and run it in netbeans then the result :run:
Thread-0 The Count is -104198536
Thread-1 The Count is 96208540
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Comment: my question how to solve the negative values shown in the results

Comment: @jarnbjo Why won't the code compile?

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
int x = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(++x); // prints out -2147483648
```

Once you reach the max value an Integer can hold, you go back to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and increment from there on. So I guess in your code `count` just goes up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and then keeps on going (as it runs for 5 seconds), ending up being negative.

If you want to hold larger values use a `long`.

Comment: in which part I can add this code

Comment: no where, it was just to demonstrate why this is happening. If you want to fix the negative values try replacing `int count` with `long count`

Comment: OK i will try it know

Comment: solved in right way ..

Comment: but why it doesn't give me negative numbers in the result when i change it to double  ?

Comment: Because the max value of `Double` is somewhere around 1.7 * 10^308, whereas the max value of int is 2147483647 (on my 64bit laptop at least). So you will take ab it more time to increment your `count` variable to `Double.MAX_VALUE` than to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` ;)

Answer (score 2):

If count will reach the Integer.MAX_VALUE then, at the next increment, it will be the Integer.MIN_VALUE.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of binary calculation.

see the byte-example.

```
00000001 is decimal 1
00000010 is decimal 2
         ...
01111111 is decimal 127
10000000 is decimal -127
10000001 is decimal -126
```

Same to a `int`.

Use a `BigInteger` instead of `int` because its an **infinite word size**-integer